# Show navbar between two div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm facing a problem in making navbar between two divs.

The code shows the navbar after first div but cant hide after second div.

I dont want to see navbar in the bottom. It has to be shown in two divs. 
Is it possible ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".navbar").hide(); //Hide the navigation bar first

  $(window).scroll(function() { //Listen for the window's scroll event
    if (isScrolledAfterElement(".content")) { //if it has scrolled beyond the #content elment
      $('.navbar').fadeIn(); //Show the navigation bar
    } else {
      $('.navbar').fadeOut(); //Else hide it
    }
  });

  //Function that returns true if the window has scrolled beyond the given element
  function isScrolledAfterElement(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;

    return elemTop <= docViewBottom;
  }
});
```

Comment: Where are the two divs? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I didnt add the html code. First div class is “content” second one is “content2”. There is a text between them.

Comment: There's no `content2` in your code. Try and come back.